# Proj.4 get 3x3 or 4x4 projection matrix

Tags: coordinate-system, c++, proj, c

How can I get a 3x3 or 4x4 transformation matrix between two CRS, using the proj4 library in C/C++?

It's OK if it makes some approximations.

Comment: Do you mean the coefficients of a conformal or affine transformation? I don't think proj4 has the functionality to calculate those.

Comment: @mkennedy yes probably something like that